# Get the actual value of a boolean attribute

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem, rspec3, rspec-expectations

I have the span:

```
<span disabled="disabled">Edit Member</span>
```

When I try to get the value of the `disabled` attribute:

```
page.in_iframe(:id => 'MembersAreaFrame') do |frame|
  expect(page.span_element(:xpath => "//span[text()='Edit Member']", :frame => frame).attribute('disabled')).to eq("disabled")
end
```

I get:

```
expected: "disabled"
     got: "true"
```

How do I get the value of specified attribute instead of a boolean value?

Comment: `....attribute('disabled').value`.

Comment: got   `undefined method 'value' for "true":String`   error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Page-Object gem's `attribute` method does not do any formatting of the attribute value. It simply returns what is returned from Selenium-WebDriver (or Watir-Webdriver).

In the case of boolean attributes, this means that true or false will be returned. From the [Selenium-WebDriver#attribute](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Element#attribute-instance_method) documentation:

> The following are deemed to be “boolean” attributes, and will return
>   either “true” or “false”:
>
> async, autofocus, autoplay, checked, compact, complete, controls,
>   declare, defaultchecked, defaultselected, defer, disabled, draggable,
>   ended, formnovalidate, hidden, indeterminate, iscontenteditable,
>   ismap, itemscope, loop, multiple, muted, nohref, noresize, noshade,
>   novalidate, nowrap, open, paused, pubdate, readonly, required,
>   reversed, scoped, seamless, seeking, selected, spellcheck, truespeed,
>   willvalidate

As you can see, the "disabled" attribute is included in this list and thus returns a boolean.

If you really want to check the actual attribute value, you will have to parse the HTML. Unless the HTML is simple, I would suggest using Nokogiri (or other HTML parser) rather than writing your own. In Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

# Get the HTML of the span
span_html = page.in_iframe(:id => 'MembersAreaFrame') do |frame|
  page.span_element(:xpath => "//span[text()='Edit Member']", :frame => frame).html
end

# Parse the span
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(span_html)
root_element = doc.at_css('*')

# Check the disabled attribute of the root element (ie the span)
expect(root_element['disabled']).to eq("disabled")
```