# Make sure that attribute "disabled" equals to "disabled"

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem, rspec-expectations

I have a span with attribute `"disabled"`

```
<span disabled="disabled" id="Apply">
```

If I try to use next expectation:

```
expect(page.spnApply_element).to have_attributes(:disabled => "disabled")
```

I get an error:

```
expected #<Watir::Span:0x..fe4257660 located=false selector={:id=>"Apply", :tag_name=>"span"}> to respond to :disabled with 0 arguments
```

How to use expectation which validate `"disabled"` attribute that it equals to `disabled`?

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previously answered question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983017/get-the-actual-value-of-a-boolean-attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30983017/1200545)? If not, can you elaborate on the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `have_attributes` method is an `RSpec` matcher used to test Ruby objects. To test the actual *HTML* attribute, you should be able to use the Watir method `attribute_value` like so:

```
expect(page.spnApply_element.attribute_value("disabled")).to be
```

Comment: getting next error:    `expected: "disabled"
            got:    "true"`

Comment: Right. In HTML5, `disabled` is an attribute that doesn't take a value (e.g. `<input type="text" disabled />`), so this is actually correct. You can match using `be_truthy` or just `be`.